# Is there a way to import images without defining a name in a React JSX file?

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, addressing

I was trying to create a Menu Site by using ReactJS.
I had some components they were all working fine,but my only problem is that my Images do not display.
I had a range of Datas and I wanted to use images for them.
They didn't work the triditonal way that we say;

```
import React from "react";

const FoodMenus = [
 {
    name: "Pizza Margherita",
    ingredients: "Tomato and mozarella",
    price: 10,
    photo: "../assets/margherita.jpg",
    soldOut: false,
  },
...
]
```

I tried all the ways of importing images like;

```
import React from "react";

const FoodMenus = [
 {
    name: "Pizza Margherita",
    ingredients: "Tomato and mozarella",
    price: 10,
    photo: "/src/assets/focaccia.jpg",
    soldOut: false,
  },
...
]
```

This didn't work as well.

Comment: You are not importing images this way, just referencing them. Either you put them in the `public` folder, or you do `import Pic from '../assets/pathToPic.jpg`

Comment: You can put your images into `public` directory(You may make the folder `images` inside of `public` and store images there instead of storing images at `src/assets`).
And set `photo` value like that: `photo: "/images/focaccia.jpg"`
Use `photo` in `img` tag, like that: `<img src={photo}  alt="your alt here" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
    import React from "react";
    import photo1 from "../assets/margherita.jpg";
    const FoodMenus = [
    {
     name: "Pizza Margherita",
     ingredients: "Tomato and mozarella",
     price: 10,
     photo: photo1,
     soldOut: false,
    },
    ...
    ]
```